# Multidimensional obstacle avoidance in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-optimization, optimal-control, nonlinear-dynamics

Artificial potential barriers are known that allow robots to avoid obstacles. They are constructed as follows. https://authors.library.caltech.edu/106548/1/2010.09819.pdf

[image]

Can you please tell me how this approach is generalized to the case of limiting several coordinates of the controlled robot?

Comment: How do you mean your question, the $x$ in the cited image is already a vector of all the coordinates, note the use of vector norm symbolic.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I understood what you are talking about, but I do not understand the following: is it possible to make a repulsive barrier for each of the variables separately (since each "penalty" term will correspond to the corresponding bounded coordinate)? Or is it better to use this formula i.e. is the normalized estimate sufficient ?

Comment: The formulas as written down are for point or circle shaped obstacles or envelopes of them. You can also define $\rho(x)$ as a more general distance function, such as the distance from a wall. This would then also give barriers/penalties for box constraints on the single variables.

Comment: @LutzLehmann And this is an interesting idea! That is, there is a certain multidimensional sphere, the radius of which for the norm of the vector of variables of the ODE system is unattainable, right? And this is a condition that the variable does not go beyond the specified limits? Are there ways to visualize this? It helped me a lot to understand this.

Comment: For the example given, you could imagine a power plant cooling tower around the obstacle with inner radius $D_{obs}$ and outer radius $D_{obs}+\rho_0$. For box constraints you get something like a half-pipe.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I was wondering if it is possible to take any ODE system, and Mathematica, apply this method of avoiding obstacles and visualize it? What should I see in the picture to understand that the system is working?

Comment: You can use any system that has numerical ODE integrators. The result is like a stream of water flowing down a parabolic bowl with its spring at the starting point and the obstacles as, relatively isolated, elevations.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thank you for your answers

I created a topic https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246413/multidimensional-obstacle-avoidance-in-ode-visualization 

Maybe ODE specialists and their visualization on Mathematica Stack Exchange can help me

Comment: @LutzLehmann https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4154326/multidimensional-obstacle-avoidance-in-ode-part-ii